# Tax implications to sell my pre-IPO shares through Sharespost

Tags: united-states, stocks, capital-gains-tax, state-income-tax, start-up

Several years ago, I was granted some RSUs from a company and I'd like to sell those RUSs in Sharespost (sharespost.com). I want understand the tax situations here.

Let's just say I paid those shares at $1 five years ago, and today they are priced at $10.

If I sell them through sharespost.com, I will be making $9. I assume I will have to pay 20% of that as long term capital gain?

What other tax implications are there?

Comment: I live in CA, USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have a long-term capital gain of $9 per share (less whatever sharespost charges you). That's about it. You'll pay Federal and State income tax (if your State taxes capital gains) on the income.